# Emacs on vnc display issues with client on Mac and server on Linux

Tags: linux, emacs, vnc, macos-highsierra

I am running Emacs, in a VNC session on a Linux machine, and it is displaying back to my Mac. My problem only occurs when I run on this particular server, and it used to work fine.

I don't know whether my issues is with VNC, Emacs, the server, my fonts, or what.

The behavior is that I'll be editing a file in an Emacs buffer, and a stretch of a few characters, very near or at the cursor position, will "disappear". However, when I refresh the display, I see that the characters are still there. But editing with this constantly happening is quite a distraction.

I've tried stopping and starting the VNC server, firing up a new Emacs, changing the default font, etc., but nothing things to solve it. Could someone explain what might be going on, and/or suggest a remedy?

Comment: And now I'm running a script that prints a bunch of lines, and there are occasional random gaps in the text. Just a few characters, here and there. Scriipt is running in a shell inside of Emacs.  So I could run it an xterm window .... and see ...

Comment: I don't see it happening. So I believe that proves that my problem lies with Emacs.